# Why is there `=` instead of `\x` in my string?

Tags: ruby, email, encoding, utf-8, escaping

I am parsing an email body text, and I have this in the source of the email:

> Questo dominio =E8 aperto e operativo da diversi anni, non riesco a =
>   capire l=92esigenza e cosa =E8 cambiato.=20

I know the client used the charset iso-8859-1. I also know that `"\xE8"` in iso-8859-1 is the charter `"é"` in utf-8:

```
"\xE8".encode "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1" # => "è"
```

Why do I find `"=E8"` instead of `"\xE8"`?

Comment: Because that's a transport encoding specific to emails. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

Comment: Can you explain further or give me some link? (sorry, I did not see the link in the notification of my app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first decode from `quoted-printable` encoding and then encode to UTF-8 from ISO-8859-1:

```
string = "Questo dominio =E8 aperto e operativo da diversi anni, non riesco a = capire l=92esigenza e cosa =E8 cambiato.=20"
puts Mail::Encodings::QuotedPrintable.decode(string).encode('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')
# => Questo dominio è aperto e operativo da diversi anni, non riesco a = capire l=92esigenza e cosa =E8 cambiato.=20
```